# A trigonometric max-min problem from an old calculus text

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

From Calculus by Varberg and Purcell, 6th Edition, 1992.  I'm Painstakingly trying to teach beginning calculus to myself, but on this question I'm stumped:

"A weight connected to a spring moves along the x-axis so that its coordinate at time t is:
$ \ x \  =  \ \sin (2t) + \sqrt3 \cos (2t) \ \ .  $ What is the farthest the weight gets from the origin?"

I found $ \ \frac{dx}{dt} \  = \ 2 \cos (2t) - 2·\sqrt3 \sin (2t) \ \ . $

Setting this equal to zero to find a critical point, $ \cos (2t) \ =\ \sqrt3 \sin (2t) \ \ . $

Even if I've done the derivation correctly (a big if), how do I translate this simple equation into a distance at time t?

My limited trigonometry skills are not helping. (I tried dividing through by $ \ \sin (2t) \ $ to end up with $ \ \tan (2t) \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \ \ , $ which even if correct, still leaves me lost just as far in the thicket.)

As always, any help is greatly appreciated, as I'm on my own out here.  Thank you to all.

Comment: You're nearly home:  $ \ \tan (2t) \ =  \ \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \ $ corresponds to angles of $ \ 30º \ $ and $ \ 210º \ \ , $ so $ \ \sin(2t) \ = \ \pm \frac12 \ $ with $ \ \cos(2t) \ = \ \pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ \ . $ Inserting those into the equation for $ \ x \ $ gives us  $$ x \ \ = \ \ \pm \frac12 \ + \ \sqrt3 · \left(\pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ \pm 2 \ \ . $$  That textbook may have a related appendix, but I would strongly suggest that you review values of trigonometric functions and trigonometric identities -- you _will_ be seeing _much_ more of them.

Comment: Thank you kindly; I now see my way through… the trig threw me; so thank you as well for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

You have\begin{align}x(t)&=\sin(2t)+\sqrt3\cos(2t)\\&=2\left(\frac12\sin(2t)+\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos(2t)\right)\\&=2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\sin(2t)+\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\cos(2t)\right)\\&=2\cos\left(\frac\pi3+2t\right),\end{align}and therefore the maximum value of $x$ is $2$.

Comment: Thank you kindly for this; much aporeciated!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.